# Trouble using dispatchEvent using Polymer and Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, polymer

I've run into a problem using the javascript function dispatchEvent in a web app using Polymer.  My code runs fine in Chrome, but in Firefox (v31 and v33), I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of EventTarget.dispatchEvent does not implement interface Event.
```

Here is the code that generates the error:

```
button.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('chosen', {'detail': value}));
```

Alternatively, I also tried:

```
var event = new Event('chosen');
event.detail = value;
button.dispatchEvent(event);
```

The result was the same: this code worked fine in Chrome, but it halted execution with the same error message when it reached the dispatchEvent.

I am pretty confident that this code should work in Firefox (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events), and indeed, this same code works fine in a non-polymer scenario in Firefox.  (In other words, if I try creating and dispatching events in either manner without any of the polymer imports / scripts, it works fine.)

My best guess is that something in the Polymer framework (platform.js or polymer.js) overrides some of the built-ins around events.  (I am using version 0.3.4.)

I've tried searching extensively, but I haven't been able to find anyone with quite the same problem.  I did find some people who had the same error message, but they were reporting it using other software (e.g., Selenium).

Polymer does supply a "fire" method that is a wrapper around the traditional event dispatching, so I will look into using that.  However, I thought I would reach out to the StackOverflow community to see if anyone had any thoughts.

Thanks in advance!

-----------Follow-up------------

Thanks for those who wrote in.  No luck getting it to work so far, but I have created a simple repro that illustrates the issue.  Here is the code for my html file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/platform/platform.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/font-roboto/roboto.html"/>
    <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html"/>

    <style>
      body {
        font-family: RobotoDraft, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
        text-align: left;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function buttonClicked(button)
      {
        alert("Button clicked: " + button);
        alert("Firing custom event foo");
        try {
          // button.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('foo'));
          button.fire('foo');
          alert("Foo fired successfully.");
        } catch (err) {
          alert("Fire event failed.");
          alert(err);
        }        
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <paper-button onclick="buttonClicked(this);">Click</paper-button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Regardless of whether I use the button.fire or the button.dispatchEvent, the code succeeds in chrome and fails in firefox.

Chrome result (either codeline):
    Button clicked: [object HTMLElement] try_button_event.html:18
    Firing custom event foo try_button_event.html:19
    Foo fired successfully.

Firefox result (button.fire):
    Button clicked: [object HTMLElement]
    Firing custom event foo
    Fire event failed.
    TypeError: button.fire is not a function

Firefox result (button.dispatchEvent):
    Button clicked: [object HTMLElement]
    Firing custom event foo
    Fire event failed.
    TypeError: Argument 1 of EventTarget.dispatchEvent does not implement interface Event.

Comment: What is `button`? A paper-button element?

Comment: Good question.  Yes, button is a <paper-button>.  I probably should have clarified that originally, but I thought this was happening on all elements.  On closer inspection, it does matter on what type of element I am invoking dispatchEvent.  elem.dispatchEvent(new Event()) works fine if elem is a plain vanilla div, or if it is a custom (polymer) element of my creating.  So this seems to be particular to <paper-button> (and perhaps other paper elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `onclick` you have prevented the ShadowDOM polyfill from managing your button.

You can fix it by *wrapping* the `button` reference inside the click method like so,

```
  function buttonClicked(button)
  {
    button = wrap(button);
```

But you are better off avoiding inline event handlers as a general rule. Here is a mod of your example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/platform/platform.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/font-roboto/roboto.html"/>
    <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html"/>

    <style>
      body {
        font-family: RobotoDraft, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
        text-align: left;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <paper-button>Click</paper-button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.querySelector('paper-button').addEventListener('click', buttonClicked);
      function buttonClicked()
      {
        alert("Button clicked: " + this);
        alert("Firing custom event foo");
        try {
          // button.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('foo'));
          this.fire('foo');
          alert("Foo fired successfully.");
        } catch (err) {
          alert("Fire event failed.");
          alert(err);
        }        
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!  The wrapping worked perfectly.  I gather from your response that using wrap() in this way is not the preferred way of doing this, however.  Is there any declarative way (e.g., on-click vs onclick?) of attaching the event handler.  Programmatically attaching the event listener seems to add unnecessary complexity.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: The browser vendors themselves want you to use imperative code to attach event listeners (`addEventListener`), the `on<event>` syntax is generally considered harmful. Polymer's `on-<event>` syntax is different because you do not put code in the attribute, only the name of a handler, but you have to opt-in to this support by using a Polymer template. If you don't want to use a full element, you can opt-in using an auto-binding template (https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#bindingoutside).

Answer (score 0):

You might try dispatching the event from the window, rather than the object. 
http://jsfiddle.net/95budad2/

```
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('chosen', {'detail': 'test'}));
```

Comment: Hmm, I might be able to do that.  In this particular case, my own custom element (call it <mike-question>) contains a number of <paper-button>'s, and I'm having the button dispatch the event as a way of communicating to the parent <mike-question> object, which listens for the event.  So having it raised by the top-level document might not work, but I might be able to have it be raised by an ancestor of the button.  I will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `button.fire(event)` to solve the immediate issue for you.

Longer term, try your code with the latest version of Polymer, and if dispatchEvent raises an exception there, I'd recommend filing an issue on the paper-button github project with a simple jsbin reproduction.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm actually getting an error that fire is not a function when I try to call button.fire.  (This is also happening only in firefox - in chrome, it works fine.)  I also tried upgrading to Polymer 4.2 - No luck there.  I'll try building a bare-bones reproduction with just a paper-button: if that still has the issue, I'll do as you suggest and file a bug.

Comment: Huh, maybe you're ending up with a different element object in Firefox? Or maybe polymer-ready hasn't yet fired? I'd be interested in seeing the reproduction if you get time to put one together.

Comment: I edited the original post to include a reproduction.

Comment: `.fire()` was removed from Polymer.Element (in v2) but it's available in `lib/legacy/legacy-element-mixin.html`.